# How do I copy a file from one server to another?

Tags: ruby

I have one server which has nothing but xls log files. Each file is 5-15Mb and it is dynamic in the sense that files get added at any point of time. Now I need a way to do the following process using Ruby.

1. Copy a file by sending the filename from one server which has nothing but log files to another server.
2. I need to pass the server password as an argument.
3. Everything happens in the background, which is triggered from a Ruby script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is how it worked**

I used the net-ssh & net-scp gem as suggested by @theTinMan and i was able to copy my files.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

Net::SSH.start("ip_address", "username",:password => "*********") do |session|
  session.scp.download! "/home/logfiles/2-1-2012/login.xls", "/home/anil/Downloads"
end
```

and to a copy a entire folder

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

Net::SSH.start("ip_address", "username",:password => "*********") do |session|
  session.scp.download!("/home/logfiles/2-1-2012", "/home/anil/Downloads",  :recursive => true)
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Check out the [Net::SCP](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-scp/frames) and [Net::SSH](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ssh/frames) gems. The first lets you retrieve a file using a secure copy, and the second will let you easily find the names of the files available for retrieval. In Net::SSH, `ssh.exec!` will be your friend.

From the [Net::SCP](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-scp/frames) docs:

> Net::SCP implements the SCP (Secure CoPy) client protocol, allowing Ruby programs to securely and programmatically transfer individual files or entire directory trees to and from remote servers. It provides support for multiple simultaneous SCP copies working in parallel over the same connection, as well as for synchronous, serial copies.
>
> Net::SCP also provides an open-uri tie-in, so you can use the Kernel#open method to open and read a remote file:

```
  # if you want to read from a URL voa SCP:
  require 'uri/open-scp'
  puts open("scp://user@remote.host/path/to/file").read
```

From the [Net::SSH](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-ssh/frames) docs:

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "password") do |ssh|
  # capture all stderr and stdout output from a remote process
  output = ssh.exec!("hostname")
```

Add an `end` to the above code to close the block. Inside the block, `output` will contain the results of the command you sent.

An alternate to retrieving the files via Ruby from the machine containing the files, would be to have Ruby initiate the transfer directly from the machine hosting the files and push them via `scp` to the other machine.

Instead of using Net::SCP and Net::SSH, you could use [Net::SFTP](http://rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/frames), to manage it all in one gem. It rides on a secure connection too, but SFTP might not be available to you. The `Net::SFTP::Operations::Dir` and `Net::SFTP::Operations::Download` classes and docs will be your friend.

Other options include using the standard `rsync` in a simple shell as @tadman mentioned. There are a multitude of ways of accomplishing this, and it is a common need in hosting environments.

---

> any other better approach?

`rsync`, at the command-line. It's very smart and can move folders and deltas of files if needed. Also, "[How to transfer files using ssh and Ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-transfer-files-using-ssh-and-ruby-512.html)" and its link to "[Ruby file upload ssh intro](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ruby-file-upload-ssh-intro)".

Melding @tadman's `rsync` recommendation with Ruby, there's "[Cheapest rsync replacement (with Ruby)](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1812)".

Comment: Boss u saved my day. net/ssh worked. Thank you very much, adding the code in question.

Comment: If he helped you you should accept the question (the little tick mark below the vote buttons), that's good SO etiquette.

Comment: @theTinMan This works for a single file, is there a way to copy the entire folder, i tried with above gem, but got    SCP did not finish successfully (1) (Net::SCP::Error)

Comment: @anil.n, "is there a way to copy the entire folder", I am not sure. From `scp` on the command-line we can do that, so, at a worst-case, you could issue the appropriate `scp` command on your logging host to push the files to the other host.

Comment: @theTinMan the reason why i need to copy the entire folder is because my logs folder may have more than 10 files, each of size 5-10Mb and earlier i used to do it manually by using scp -r, now i want the script to do the entire process. Is there a way to do by using above gem or any other better approach?

Comment: Will these methods work for Linux to Windows or Windows to Windows transfers as well, or does it rely solely on the SSH program on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use `rsync` instead of rolling your own thing. Use `ssh` with public/private key access and you will avoid a password. Using a password at all is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Some companies don't allow key access. It is a pain having to deal with passwords, but it is also part of their security policy.

Comment: Some companies have IT departments staffed with trolls, too. Passwords can be guessed. Keys have to be stolen.

Comment: That may be. The fact remains that some places require passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is possible without scp

```
@session = Net::SSH.start(@ftpIp, @ftpUser, :password => @ftpPass)
@conn = Net::SFTP::Session.new(@session).connect!

def download_remote_folder(remote_path, local_path, use_ssh = @use_ssh)
    @conn ||= connect
    if (use_ssh)
      @conn.download!(remote_path,local_path,:recursive => true)
    else
      @conn.get(remote_path, local_path)
    end
  end

  def download_remote_file(remote_path, local_path, use_ssh = @use_ssh)
    @conn ||= connect
    if (use_ssh)
      @conn.download!(remote_path,local_path)
    else
      @conn.get_file(remote_path, local_path)
    end
  end
```