# How to list directories of a remote website with Ruby

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems, filesystems

I am having some difficulty utilizing `Dir.glob()` on remote sites.  Can `Dir.glob()` be used only on local directories?

Is there another method to list remote directories/files on an external web server using Ruby/Rubygems?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe more, since on the surface this looks like a request to help with blackhat stuff

Comment: What kind of remote sites? In general this is only possible if a host exposes an interface for listing files. `Dir.glob()` will work on remote mounted file systems for instance, but is not smart enough to ask for listings from FTP servers or web servers, even if they are available.

Comment: I am trying to list files/folders from my web server that are within the /upload/media directory.  Trying to verify the contents of my picture directory.

Comment: `Dir.glob` only works on filesystems of the machine it is run on. If you mount that dir of your server (e.g. via NFS or CIFS or whatever) it will work. If not, you have to ask your webserver to send the data. And you need other means (e.g. HTTP) to get them.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the server? Does `ssh you@host ls /upload/media` work for you?

Comment: Yes, I do have ssh to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding `Dir.glob` only working on local file systems.

Answer (score 2):

`Dir.glob` only works on local file systems or mounted file systems.

The [Net::SSH](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh) gem can help you connect to a remote server and execute a command which will list directories, and transport the response from the remote server to you.  More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732174/445131

Answer (score 1):

As you have SSH access to the server, you can automate that in Ruby:

```
require 'net/ssh'
ssh = Net::SSH.start( 'host', 'user' )
files = ssh.exec!( 'ls /upload/media' ).split( "\n" )
ssh.close()
```